# Is there any software to simulate quantum random number generation using optical elements?

Tags: optics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-optics, software

I want to implement a simulation of a quantum random number generation protocol using optical elements. Is there any software that's typically used for such things? Ideally, I would want control over all devices used, such as detector efficiency, dead-time, mean photon rate of source, etc. The method should be able to simulate the experiment outlined in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.02828). They use continuous photon sources with detectors for carrying out the bell test.